# Keyboard Shortcuts in Tooltips in macOS Calculator

Tags: keyboard

Is there something that can be done so that the tooltip text indicates the keyboard shortcut associated with each button in the macOS calculator? It's frustrating to have to [look it up online](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/calculator/welcome/mac) every time.

Currently, the tooltip text contains only a description of the button, not its shortcut.

I'm on Calculator Version 10.14 (123) on Catalina 10.15.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tooltip text (presented on hovering the mouse cursor over the Calculator app buttons) does show the keyboard shortcut. The following is a screenshot from Calculator app version Version 10.14 (123), running in macOS Catalina 10.5.1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Weird. It seems that when in RPN mode, some of these buttons don't display this (for example, x^y). (I'm also on Version 10.14 (123) on Catalina 10.15.1.)